# Latex lstinputlisting line highlighting

Tags: listings, fancyhdr

I am using lstinputlisting to reference a piece of source code, for which has a caption and label, as shown below.

```
\lstinputlisting[caption={Caption}, label={code:arbitrary}]{directory/arbitrary}
```

My desire is to highlight specific lines of the source code, I tried researching this and found people with similar issues, and the suggestion is to use `\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}`.

However, whenever I implement this package into my tex file I get the following error appear at my,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
```

> File `fancyhdr.sty' not found.

EDIT:
It appears that wherever I the `\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}` the next line will throw an error, for example if I were to do

```
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}

\usepackage{apacite}
```

I get the error `File 'apacite.sty' not found.`

EDIT 2:
As requested a minimum working example is below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption={test}, label={test}]{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither `lstlinebgrd.sty` nor `listings.sty` refer to fancyhdr, so I guess the error must come from something else. Moreover, `fancyhdr.sty` not found is very strange, as it should be a standard package in your TeX system.
Please check your log file to see which package or line causes the error message.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I have edited the question to elaborate further.

Comment: Are you using a complicated style with your listing? Can you provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your setup? Something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` *including* sample code you want to include? Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner edited question based on your request.

Comment: @user41245213: So you don't use any special code formatting? For example, what is in `test`? Is it Python code, or perhaps C++, or just something you want printed verbatim?

Comment: @Werner the test file was just multiple lines of plain text as a test. My issue is not with the listing itself. I want to be able to highlight a specified line.

Comment: I don't get your error. However, I get anohter error: ERROR: Package Listings Error: Numbers none unknown.
It seems `lstlinebgrd.sty` is incompatible with modern `listings.sty`, but you seem to have either one or both different from me. The error I get can be repaired by making a copy of `lstlinebgrd.sty` and replacing the 3 `&` characters with `:`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Sorry to ask but how do you make a copy of lstlinebgrd.sty? I am new to LaTeX, in my file directory I only have a .bib, .aux, .bbl, .blg, .fls, .listing, .log, .pdf, .run.xml, synctex.gz, .synctex, .tex and a .toc.

Comment: You can find the location of `lstlinebgrd.sty` on your disk in the log file. Open that file in a text editor, make the changes and then save it to the directory where your document is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option: You manually specify the lines you want coloured (and with what `<colour>`) using `\lstcolourline{<colour>}` and using the `escapechar=<char>` to insert it in the appropriate lines in your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\lstcolourline}[1]{\rlap{\color{#1}\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip}}}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.txt}
first line
second line
@\lstcolourline{green!15}@third line
fourth line
@\lstcolourline{red!15}@fifth line
sixth line
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[caption={test},escapechar=@]{test.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it requires the code to be pasted into the tex file. Instead I want to purely use lstinputlisting to grab the source code for me. Unless I am mistaking the functionality of your tex file.

Comment: @user41245213: You'll have to manually insert the `@\lstcolourline{<colour>}@` entries within your file (`test.txt`). I created `test.txt` as part of my minimal code using `filecontents`.